# Nested JSON blob in Snowflake

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, blob

I'm trying to query on the following JSON Blobs in MyTable that is varchar, however, JSONBlob2 has square brackets over the curly brackets that seem to be interfering with my query:

**MyTable**

| JSONBlob | JSONBlob2 |
| --- | --- |
| {"a": "12345", "b": {"c":"567", "d":"llc"} } | {"e": [{"f":"321", "g":"432}] "h": [{"i":"couch", "j":"sofa"}] } |
| {"a": "6789", "b": {"c":"999", "d":"col"} } | {"e": [{"f":"765", "g":"444}] "h": [{"i":"bed", "j":"blanket"}] } |

What I've tried so far that is returning no results for JSONBlob2:

```
select jb:e:f::text f, jb:h:i::text h
  from (select PARSE_JSON(JSONBlob2) jb
          from myTable)
```

hoping to get the results in this format:

| f | i |
| --- | --- |
| 321 | couch |
| 765 | bed |

Comment: it is an array, so index it. If it only have 1 value, a fixed value of zero will work like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`FLATTEN`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten) to convert the JSON into rows :

```
select 
       max(get( jb.value[0], 'f' ))::varchar f,
       max(get( jb.value[0], 'i' ))::varchar i
from myTable,
lateral flatten (  parse_json(JSONBlob2) )  jb
group by jb.seq
```

Result :

| F | I |
| --- | --- |
| 321 | couch |
| 765 | bed |

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON in `jsonblob2` is not valid, assuming the invalid comes from you type "fake data" to protect your real data (thus I hand fixed it), we can then access it via a [array index](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-semistructured#parsing-arrays-directly-from-a-staged-data-file):

```
with data(JSONBlob2) as (
    select * from values
    ( '{"e": [{"f":"321", "g":"432"}], "h": [{"i":"couch", "j":"sofa"}] }'),
    ( '{"e": [{"f":"765", "g":"444"}], "h": [{"i":"bed", "j":"blanket"}] }')
)
select
    try_parse_json(JSONBlob2):e[0]:f::text as f
    ,try_parse_json(JSONBlob2):h[0].i::text as i
from data
```

I was lazy and didn't use the nested try_parse_json like demircioglu did.

[image]

Where-as if your data really looks like "how you show" that is not JSON, and ether the source should output it correctly, or you have a horrible string processing task ahead of you.